# How do I decide the frequency of data capture for modeling?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, dataset, frequency

I plan to capture data to predict energy consumption in a food processing plant. I want to capture production details such as how much each category of food is produced, what is the machine's output, any downtime details etc.
What frequency of data is required for this analysis? What factors should be taken into consideration while deciding the data frequency?
I can capture data at five minutes/1 hour or one shift(8 hours). How do I decide on this?
I want to interpret the model and determine the top factors (features) driving my energy consumption.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is there a problem with collecting every 5 minutes? More data are almost always better. Are there substantial costs to collecting the data that frequently? How frequently in time do you expect there to be changes? There's a whole literature on [sampling frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem): the fidelity of what you reconstruct, problems from poorly chosen sampling frequencies, etc. Please address those tradeoffs by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: If you collect too much data, you can always downsample it or aggregate it, not possible the other way around. The consideration is only the cost of collecting and storing it.

Comment: The only reason to collect less data would be collecting cost (storage and other infra)